# Problems Creating UWP Apps with FTDI

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, ftdi

I haven't been able to create a Windows Universal App using FTDIs'FTD2XX DLL  .net wrapper dll. My goal is to create this and run it on both Windows 10 Pro and Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 3. None of the samples below are UWP apps.

https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp.htm

I've already tried to add the FTDI 2XX through Nuget and manually. Neither worked. I was never able to create a new FTDI Object. I remembered to include a 'using' statement.

Comment: Wrapper for what? What solution? FTDI creates thousands of products. Many of them are serial over USB adapters that *shouldn't* require any wrappers.

Comment: Does the link give you a better idea?     "FTDI devices through the D2XX drivers and FTD2XX.DLL"

Comment: you still don't explain what you're trying to do or what you're trying to connect to. That link is just a page with samples that may or may not be relevant, assuming they're up to data. I've used FTDI chips to talk to devices in the past so over serial so I can guess that's what you want to do too, and you don't want to, or don't know how, to connect through the virtual COM ports.

Comment: This page mentions Windows and C#, but that doesn't say the DLLs are compiled for *ARM* CPUs.

Comment: Excellent point. If I wanted to create just something for Windows 10 Pro, then it should be possible.

Comment: The file is 3 years old and contains only a single DLL. I'd bet it's *not* for ARM. In general, my experience with FTDI was ... yeah well. Check [this article though](http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/666/win-10-iot-core-ftdi-serial-driver)

Comment: Check [this MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c1b0480-a797-4902-b238-6c9606d1b2b7/how-to-install-ftdi-driver-in-db410c-running-windows-10-iot-core?forum=WindowsIoT) and David Jone's article [Win 10 IoT Core: FTDI Serial Driver](http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/666/win-10-iot-core-ftdi-serial-driver). Looks like FTDI devices weren't supported in 2018 either. Jones' article mentions the Windows RT drivers for ARM which can be found [in the drivers page](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm)

Comment: You've clarified my question considerably. I'll mark your answer as correct.Thank you!

Comment: Check [this page too](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/FTReferenceDesigns.html). It's a Windows IoT project on RPi that *does* use FTDI D2XX chips. Annoyingly, I can't find a clear download link for the "FTDI D2XX UWP Driver". You may have to dig around or just try with the WinRT driver

Comment: Looks like the Windows IoT Colour meter source code contains the driver in the Library folder. The direct link is https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/reference_design/AN_475_Source.zip

Comment: If you post an answer, I will mark it correct. Thank you for sharing your knowledge about FTDI.